# Facbeook app with form posting from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: post, https, facebook-apps, mixed-content

I have a facebook app that is basically an iframe of my website.

My website runs on **HTTPS** and has a form that has a POST action to `/list-items`. On the server, it renders a page that on the jQuery's `$(document).ready()` make an AJAX call to populate a list of items - everything the good'ol JSP (Java server pages), so basically the shell is a document `shell.jsp` and the ajax call returns a `list.jsp`.

Using the website directly from the browser it acts correctly, maintaining the **HTTPS** url, but when I use it inside facebook, on its iframe version, what happens is that I cannot submit the form, since facebook says it is trying to post to a **HTTP** page, giving the user this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.facebook.com/xxxx/app/77777/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://www.example.com/77777'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can I solve this problem without putting the absolute path with `//example.com/list-item` or `https://example.com/list-item`?